# Unable to install packages or use certain libraries due to SSLCertVerificationError

Tags: python, ssl-certificate

I work behind a corporate VPN and attempting to install any packages in Python using `pip` or running an `requests` statements end in a similar error:

`There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443)`

I understand that there are several workarounds available, such as [setting the `--trusted-host`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi/29751768#29751768) parameters when running `pip install`.  However, when using libraries that use `requests`, I am not able to avoid the error.

For example, I was able to install `geocoder`, but the error appears again because `geocoder` uses `requests` to retrieve the JSON data from Google.

Is there a permanent solution to this? I have also tried the suggested solution of adding the trusted hosts to my `%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini` without success.

Comment: Does this happen when you use a proxy server or going direct?

Comment: I ran into similar issues and usually end up reaching out to security team to get exceptions added in corporate firewall.

Comment: @JamesMcPherson - I assume direct, as I don't explicitly use a proxy. I am not 100% familiar with how my organization's VPN connection is routed, though.